# Does Stack Exchange have a backup plan in the case of an overwhelming amount of irrelevant content?

Tags: discussion, traffic

I was recently using Physics Stack Exchange when suddenly, in 1 hour, a lot of new questions started coming up. I was just wondering if a group of people (maybe a rival company) started a program to fill Stack Exchange with lots of irrelevant content through questions, comments and other ways. How would Stack Exchange counter this?

Comment: What kind of questions? Spam i.e. unsolicited advertising or just off-topic questions?

Comment: any type of question with intention to spam, the one recently added where very basics homework like question which just mentions question and then asks for solution

Comment: spam has to advertise something, basic homework questions would seem harmless, find duplicates, answer them or close them if they aren't on topic i.e. too broad or unclear etc.

Comment: You are the back-up plan. Vote (down/close/delete) or flag questions that don't fit the scope of a site or are low quality. If we finally found a bot that can ask awesome questions right of the bat, we're all good.

Comment: @rene the downvotes and closevote come after some high reputation which most of the users don't have

Comment: downvotes come at 125 rep, flagging privilege starts at 15. Don't expect others to fix something we can fix ourselves.

Comment: Re *"...to fill Stack Exchange with lots of irrelevant content"*: [There is a theory which states](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuCqeg4zV_o&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2&t=51s) that this [has already happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

Comment: Backup plan is for extreme cases where the whole network goes down for long period of time. Spam waves do not require any "backup", the sites still working just fine and the site active users and mods would handle it eventually.

Comment: Physics.SE has a *very* strict policy concerning homework (or homework-like) questions; see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714 & https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093 For a while, we got *lots* of low-quality homework questions, but they're much less common these days, and they're usually dealt with fairly quickly, although you may see the occasional wave of such questions at the start of school terms.

Comment: I am not able to understand why my question is downvoted without any suggestions to improve the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a sense - the Stack Exchange system as it is designed manages it, through the effect of users casting downvotes, closevotes and flags. A user who posts poor quality content will find themselves question or answer banned, suspended or otherwise hobbled. Moderators also have additional tools like suspensions to deal with problem users.

Should a user attempt to persistently evade such restrictions, or should there be an obvious sign of organized malicious behavior - the moderator team may request CM assistance to deal with it.

Comment: The downvotes, closevotes and flags are all given by users and are not system generated, right?

Comment: @TeslaBolt: Yes, except the automatic downvote cast after raising a spam flag. Seeing that you're new, you might want to go through this [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/513150).

Comment: Well - the users *are* part of the system

Comment: @justin So overall someone has to raise a flag or downvote or closevote, but I have seen doubt sites online where there are so many users posting anything random- I don't think if that even if all the users are given privilege to do downvotes and things, still it will be hard to fight until its something system generated

Comment: @TeslaBolt And what would such a system look like? Automatically determining whether something is garbage or not is only achievable after having manually determined it's garbage (that's how spamfilters and anti-virus work). If enough users actually use the privileges they've been given, the system works.

Comment: @mast Ok you are right if nothing is happening then mostly the system is working perfectly.

Comment: Also automatic question and answer bans exist.